# Performance of BucketedRandomProjectionLSH (org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSH)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

Hi I am using the `BucketedRandomProjectionLSH` (2 buckets 3 hash tables) algorithm to find similar people in a dataset of ~300,000 records. I am creating a sparse vector of bigrams for each record (1296 dimensions in each vector) and doing an approximate similarity self join on the dataset which as I mentioned is not too large. 
On an 3 node spark cluster (Master:m3.xlarge, Core:2 m4.4xlarge), it takes ~7 hours to complete. 
The performance is too slow and I am looking for some benchmarks that someone may have created for this algorithm. Additionally, any guidance on how to tune this algorithm will be really helpful.

Here is the code snippet for your reference:

```
val rdd=sc.loadFromMongoDB(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://localhost:27017/Single.master","readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred")))
val aggregatedRdd = rdd.withPipeline(Seq(Document.parse("{$unwind:'$sources'}"),Document.parse("{$project:{_id:0,id:'$sources._id',val:{$toLower:{$concat:['$sources.first_name','$sources.middle_name','$sources.last_name',{$substr:['$sources.gender',0,1]},'$sources.dob','$sources.address.street','$sources.address.city','$sources.address.state','$sources.address.zip','$sources.phone','$sources.email']}}}}")))
val fDF=aggregatedRdd.map(line=>line.values()).map(ll=>bigramMap(ll.toArray)).toDF("id","idx","keys")
val columnNames = Seq("idx","keys")
val result = fDF.select(columnNames.head, columnNames.tail: _*)
val brp = new BucketedRandomProjectionLSH().setBucketLength(2).setNumHashTables(3).setInputCol("keys").setOutputCol("values")
val model = brp.fit(result)
var outDD=model.approxSimilarityJoin(result, result, 100).filter("datasetA.idx < datasetB.idx").select(col("datasetA.idx").alias("idA"),col("datasetB.idx").alias("idB"),col("distCol"))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad to answer. Please read about how to ask a good question on SO !

Comment: @elisah Thanks for the comment. I am looking for some benchmarks on this algorithm and some guidance on how to tune it. I will try reframing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried BucketedRandomProjectionLSH  to 10,000,000 data.
It takes 3hours.
I only stored Dataframe's cash before.

`df.persist()`